# How would I get every blank row?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get and then delete every blank row in a spreadsheet. If a row with values contains a blank cell, I want to delete that row too.

I don't want to delete just the rows that are past the row with the last values, I want to delete every blank row.

For example,

```
-1 2 3 4 5
-1 2 3 4 5
-          << delete row
-1 2 3 4 5
-          << delete row
-          << delete row
-1 2 3 4 5
-1 2   4 5 << delete row -- cell is blank
-          << delete row
```

`.getDataRange` doesn't seem to get the blank rows, so how would I go about getting all the rows in a for loop?

---

**edit**

```
var artistFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId); //open artists spreadsheet
var artistFileRows = artistFile.getActiveSheet().getMaxRows(); //get number of rows in spreadsheet -- 1 = no values (only headers are in the sheet), 2+ = values (headers + values are in the sheet)

Logger.log(artistFileRows);
var startRange = "A1";
var endRange = "F" + artistFileRows;
var totalRange = startRange + ":" + endRange;
Logger.log(totalRange);
var allValues = artistFile.getRange(totalRange).getValues();

for (var a = 0; a < allValues.length; a++)
{
  Logger.log("row " + parseInt(a + 1) + ": " + allValues[a]);

  if (allValues[a] === '')
  {
    Logger.log("true");
  }
  else
  {
    Logger.log("false");
  }
}
```

---

```
var artistFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId); //open artists spreadsheet
var artistFileRows = artistFile.getActiveSheet().getMaxRows(); //get number of rows in spreadsheet -- 1 = no values (only headers are in the sheet), 2+ = values (headers + values are in the sheet)

Logger.log(artistFileRows);
var startRange = "A1";
var endRange = "F" + artistFileRows;
var totalRange = startRange + ":" + endRange;
Logger.log(totalRange);
var allValues = artistFile.getRange(totalRange).getValues();

for (var a = 0; a < allValues.length; a++)
{
  //Logger.log("row " + parseInt(a + 1) + ": " + allValues[a]);

  for (//iterate through each value in the row)
  {
    Logger.log(//each value in the row);
  }
}
```

---

code:

```
for (var a = 0; a < allValues.length; a++)
{
  //Logger.log("row " + parseInt(a + 1) + ": " + allValues[a]);

  for (var b = 0; b < allValues[a].length; b++)
  {
    Logger.log(allValues[a][b]);

    if (allValues[a][b] === '')
    {
      Logger.log("true");
      //artistFile.deleteRow(a);
    }
  }
}
```

execution transcript:

```
[16-10-13 19:24:54:885 EDT] 10.0
[16-10-13 19:24:54:885 EDT] A1:F10
[16-10-13 19:24:54:917 EDT] Date
[16-10-13 19:24:54:918 EDT] h1
[16-10-13 19:24:54:918 EDT] h2
[16-10-13 19:24:54:919 EDT] h3
[16-10-13 19:24:54:919 EDT] h4
[16-10-13 19:24:54:920 EDT] h5
[16-10-13 19:24:54:921 EDT] d2
[16-10-13 19:24:54:921 EDT] td2
[16-10-13 19:24:54:922 EDT] ca2
[16-10-13 19:24:54:922 EDT] cr2
[16-10-13 19:24:54:923 EDT] t2
[16-10-13 19:24:54:923 EDT] ns2
[16-10-13 19:24:54:924 EDT] d3
[16-10-13 19:24:54:924 EDT] td3
[16-10-13 19:24:54:924 EDT] ca3
[16-10-13 19:24:54:925 EDT] cr3
[16-10-13 19:24:54:925 EDT] t3
[16-10-13 19:24:54:926 EDT] ns3
[16-10-13 19:24:54:926 EDT] 
[16-10-13 19:24:54:926 EDT] true
[16-10-13 19:24:54:927 EDT] 
[16-10-13 19:24:54:927 EDT] true
[16-10-13 19:24:54:927 EDT] 
[16-10-13 19:24:54:928 EDT] true
[16-10-13 19:24:54:928 EDT] 
[16-10-13 19:24:54:929 EDT] true
[16-10-13 19:24:54:929 EDT] 
[16-10-13 19:24:54:929 EDT] true
[16-10-13 19:24:54:930 EDT] 
[16-10-13 19:24:54:930 EDT] true
[16-10-13 19:24:54:930 EDT] 
[16-10-13 19:24:54:931 EDT] true
[16-10-13 19:24:54:931 EDT] 
[16-10-13 19:24:54:932 EDT] true
[16-10-13 19:24:54:932 EDT] 
[16-10-13 19:24:54:932 EDT] true
[16-10-13 19:24:54:933 EDT] 
[16-10-13 19:24:54:933 EDT] true
[16-10-13 19:24:54:933 EDT] 
[16-10-13 19:24:54:934 EDT] true
[16-10-13 19:24:54:934 EDT] 
[16-10-13 19:24:54:934 EDT] true
[16-10-13 19:24:54:935 EDT] d4
[16-10-13 19:24:54:935 EDT] td4
[16-10-13 19:24:54:936 EDT] ca4
[16-10-13 19:24:54:936 EDT] cr4
[16-10-13 19:24:54:936 EDT] t4
[16-10-13 19:24:54:937 EDT] ns4
[16-10-13 19:24:54:937 EDT] test1
[16-10-13 19:24:54:938 EDT] test1
[16-10-13 19:24:54:938 EDT] test1
[16-10-13 19:24:54:938 EDT] test1
[16-10-13 19:24:54:939 EDT] test1
[16-10-13 19:24:54:939 EDT] test1
[16-10-13 19:24:54:940 EDT] 
[16-10-13 19:24:54:940 EDT] true
[16-10-13 19:24:54:940 EDT] 
[16-10-13 19:24:54:941 EDT] true
[16-10-13 19:24:54:941 EDT] 
[16-10-13 19:24:54:941 EDT] true
[16-10-13 19:24:54:942 EDT] 
[16-10-13 19:24:54:942 EDT] true
[16-10-13 19:24:54:943 EDT] 
[16-10-13 19:24:54:943 EDT] true
[16-10-13 19:24:54:943 EDT] 
[16-10-13 19:24:54:944 EDT] true
[16-10-13 19:24:54:944 EDT] test2
[16-10-13 19:24:54:945 EDT] test2
[16-10-13 19:24:54:945 EDT] test2
[16-10-13 19:24:54:945 EDT] test2
[16-10-13 19:24:54:946 EDT] test2
[16-10-13 19:24:54:946 EDT] test2
[16-10-13 19:24:54:946 EDT] 
[16-10-13 19:24:54:947 EDT] true
[16-10-13 19:24:54:947 EDT] 
[16-10-13 19:24:54:948 EDT] true
[16-10-13 19:24:54:948 EDT] 
[16-10-13 19:24:54:948 EDT] true
[16-10-13 19:24:54:949 EDT] 
[16-10-13 19:24:54:949 EDT] true
[16-10-13 19:24:54:949 EDT] 
[16-10-13 19:24:54:950 EDT] true
[16-10-13 19:24:54:950 EDT] 
[16-10-13 19:24:54:951 EDT] true
```

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: No. I have the rows, and I iterated through the values in that row, but when I tried to delete the row, it deleted more non blank rows as well as blank rows.

Comment: Did you try adding 1 to a to account for the fact that rows are 1 based and not 0 based? Check my answer out.

Comment: The index a is relative to the range variable, and does not apply to the whole worksheet

Comment: check out my new answer and tell me if it did it.

Comment: Cant do .getCell from allValues... allValues is the values from the range A1:F10 in the spreadsheet. It's doing an error because it cant find the object getCell in the values.

Comment: please tell me this did it !!

Comment: Nope, it says `Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot call method "getValues" of undefined.`. It's from `for (var n = 0; n < allValues[a].getValues().length; n++)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125647/discussion-between-lucas-kot-zaniewski-and-user4411473).

Answer (score 1):

Either start with the last row and iterate backwards or start with the first row and decrement your iterator by 1 everytime a delete is performed.

```
var startRange = "A1";
var endRange = "F" + artistFileRows;
var totalRange = startRange + ":" + endRange;
var allValues = artistFile.getRange(totalRange).getValues();

for (var a = 0; a < artistFileRows; a++)
{
   for (var n = 0; n < allValues[a].length; n++)
   {
      if(allValues[a][n] === '') 
     {
             artistFile.getActiveSheet().deleteRow(a+1);
             a--;
             break;
     }
   }


}
```

Comment: How would I tell when a row contains a blank cell or the whole row is blank? I can get every row including blank rows with `.getMaxRows()` -- it just gives me a number like 10.0

Comment: I'm not sure how I would iterate through all the cells... `.getDataRange` doesn't give me every row, but `.getMaxRows()` does. How do i iterate throught `.getMaxRows()` when it only gives me the row numbers?

Comment: I added to the post what I've done so far. The if statement is working... Is that the way to iterate through the values and compare it to ''?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. How come it's not displaying `true` for cells that have blank values?

Comment: I think it's because I'm getting the whole row and comparing it to ''. What would I have to do to get each cell from that row? Another for loop iterating through that row to get each cell and then compare them to ''?

Comment: getValues() returns a rectangular grid according to google documentation. I'll update my answer. basically you need two indexes

Comment: It's not working...I added what it's logging to the post.

Comment: how about now, I recommend reading the documentation.....https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#