# How would I get multiple rows one by one and check their values?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

What I'm trying to accomplish:

- Get every row in spreadsheet, starting with first row and ending at the last row
- get the values in that row
- compare values to ''
- if any value in that row == '', delete that row and then continue to the next row
- else continue to next row and repeat

---

This is what I have so far. I can get every row in the spreadsheet and their values. I'm not sure how to get a row one by one and then move to the next row after I check that rows values.

```
var artistFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId); //open spreadsheet
var artistFileRows = artistFile.getActiveSheet().getMaxRows(); //get number of rows in spreadsheet

var startL = "A"; //start column
var endL = "F"; //end column

//get row one by one
for (var a = 0; a < artistFileRows; a++)
{
  var range = startL + parseInt(a + 1) + ":" + endL + parseInt(a + 1); //range = A1:AX -- X == last row number in spreadsheet

  //get rows values
  var values = artistFile.getRange(range).getValues();

  //compare rows values to ''

  //delete rows with blank values

  //move to next row and repeat
}
```

This gives me a log of

```
[16-10-14 20:50:34:622 EDT] row: 1, range: A1:F1
[16-10-14 20:50:34:646 EDT] [[header1, header2, header3, header4, header5, header6]]
[16-10-14 20:50:34:647 EDT] row: 2, range: A2:F2
[16-10-14 20:50:34:671 EDT] [[d2, td2, ca2, cr2, t2, ns2]]
[16-10-14 20:50:34:672 EDT] row: 3, range: A3:F3
[16-10-14 20:50:34:695 EDT] [[d3, td3, ca3, cr3, t3, ns3]]
[16-10-14 20:50:34:696 EDT] row: 4, range: A4:F4
[16-10-14 20:50:34:722 EDT] [[, , , , , ]]
[16-10-14 20:50:34:722 EDT] row: 5, range: A5:F5
[16-10-14 20:50:34:748 EDT] [[, , , , , ]]
[16-10-14 20:50:34:748 EDT] row: 6, range: A6:F6
[16-10-14 20:50:34:774 EDT] [[d4, td4, ca4, cr4, t4, ns4]]
[16-10-14 20:50:34:775 EDT] row: 7, range: A7:F7
[16-10-14 20:50:34:799 EDT] [[test1, test1, test1, test1, test1, test1]]
[16-10-14 20:50:34:799 EDT] row: 8, range: A8:F8
[16-10-14 20:50:34:825 EDT] [[, , , , , ]]
[16-10-14 20:50:34:825 EDT] row: 9, range: A9:F9
[16-10-14 20:50:34:849 EDT] [[test2, test2, test2, test2, test2, test2]]
[16-10-14 20:50:34:850 EDT] row: 10, range: A10:F10
[16-10-14 20:50:34:874 EDT] [[t, , t, , , ]]
[16-10-14 20:50:34:874 EDT] row: 11, range: A11:F11
[16-10-14 20:50:34:899 EDT] [[, , , , , ]]
```

---

**edit**

log:

```
[16-10-19 01:28:52:863 EDT] Spreadsheet.deleteRow([3]) [0.06 seconds]
[16-10-19 01:28:52:914 EDT] Spreadsheet.deleteRow([4]) [0.051 seconds]
[16-10-19 01:28:52:967 EDT] Spreadsheet.deleteRow([7]) [0.053 seconds]
[16-10-19 01:28:52:989 EDT] Spreadsheet.deleteRow([9]) [0.021 seconds]
[16-10-19 01:28:52:992 EDT] Execution failed: Those rows are out of bounds.
```

code:

```
var count = 0;
var index = [];

for (var i = 0; i < allValues.length; i++)
{
  for (var j = 0; j < allValues[i].length; j++)
  {
    Logger.log(allValues[i][j]);
    if (allValues[i][j] === "")
    {
      index[count] = i;
      count++;
      break;
    }
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
  artistFile.deleteRow(index[i]);
}
```

**edit 2**

I fixed the `.deleteRow()` showing the wrong rows being deleted. The for loop starts as `var i = 0`, but the rows in the spreadsheet start from row 1. I changed the `.deleteRow()` to `artistFile.deleteRow(parseInt(index[i] + 1));`.

It now shows the right rows that need to be deleted:

```
[16-10-19 01:40:01:353 EDT] Spreadsheet.deleteRow([4]) [0.053 seconds]
[16-10-19 01:40:01:406 EDT] Spreadsheet.deleteRow([5]) [0.052 seconds]
[16-10-19 01:40:01:461 EDT] Spreadsheet.deleteRow([8]) [0.054 seconds]
[16-10-19 01:40:01:484 EDT] Spreadsheet.deleteRow([10]) [0.023 seconds]
[16-10-19 01:40:01:488 EDT] Execution failed: Those rows are out of bounds.
```

And the last row before the error should show `.deleteRow([11])`.

But, I'm still getting an error - `Execution failed: Those rows are out of bounds.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I get every blank row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40027874/how-would-i-get-every-blank-row)

Comment: when deleting, work your way backwards from last to first row in the loop so row indexes wont shift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will surely work:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var count = 0;
    var index = [];

//find the rows which contain
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
   for(var j=0;j<data[i].length;j++)
   {
   Logger.log(" Row : "+i+" Column : "+j);
      if(data[i][j]=="" || data[i][j]==" ")
      {
         index[count]=i+1;
         Logger.log(index[count]);
         count++;
         break;
      }
   }
}

//delete the rows
for(var i=0;i<count;i++)
{
   sheet.deleteRow(index[i]-i);
   Logger.log("Row "+index[i]+" deleted");
}
```

Comment: In the previous code..every time a row is deleted the index of the successive rows changes...so while deleting multiple rows in a single loop, we need to make sure we update the index of the rows.

Comment: Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code:

```
var artistFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId); //open spreadsheet
var sheet = artisiFile.getSheetByName(SheetName); //open the sheet where the data is stored
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var count = 0;
var index = [];

//find the rows which contain "
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
   for(var j=0;j<data[i].length;j++)
   {
      if(data[i][j]=="\"")
      {
         index[count]=i;
         count++;
      }
   }
}

//delete the rows
for(var i=0;i<count;i++)
{
   sheet.deleteRow(index[i]);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also delete rows that weren't meant to be deleted?

Comment: No it wont. The variable index is storing the index of the row in which the match is found in the first nested loop. Whereas in the next loop it is deleting only those rows where the match was found.

Comment: I'm getting an error - `Execution failed: Those rows are out of bounds.` for `.deleteRow(index[i]);`.

Also, it deleted rows that didn't have blank values in them...

Comment: could you share the link of the spreadsheet you're working on? Or can you atleast take a screenshot of the spreadsheet? Just want to make sure if i'm understanding the format in which you have your data correctly.

Comment: https://snag.gy/LZkt7v.jpg is the spreadsheet. It's not limited to 11 rows... the spreadsheet will have less or more rows depending on how many values someone needs to enter. Also, I'm using `.getMaxRows();` because `.getDataRange();` doesnt get blank rows.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
 var artistFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId); //open spreadsheet
    var sheet = artisiFile.getSheetByName(SheetName); //open the sheet where the data is stored
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var count = 0;
    var index = [];

//find the rows which contain "
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
   for(var j=0;j<data[i].length;j++)
   {
      if(data[i][j]=="")
      {
         index[count]=i;
         count++;
         break;
      }
   }
}

//delete the rows
for(var i=0;i<count;i++)
{
   sheet.deleteRow(index[i]);
}
```

PS. I've only made 2 changes.

1) replaced `"\""` by `""` (because i had misunderstood the detail in the requirement)

2) added a `break;` statement (this will make sure that the rows which are not to be deleted wont be deleted)

Comment: Still getting the same error. I'll edit the original post with the log and the code.